# Why does summing up two inequalities alter the solution?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

Sorry for the basic question. But take for example:

$$3x-8\leq 0$$

$$-2+3x-x^2\leq 0$$

If we sum these two inequalities we obtain:
$$0\leq x^2-6x+10$$

The solution of this inequality is of course any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. However, we can also attempt to solve them separetly and obtain:
$$x 
\leq 8/3$$
$$(x-2)(x-1)\geq 0$$

which of course implies that $x \in (-\infty,1]\cup[2,8/3]$.

Comment: Solving separately is the right way. The first method doesn't give us new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, for all real numbers $a,b$,
$$
a\le0,\quad b\le0 \implies a+b \le 0
$$ and we **don't have**
$$
a\le0,\quad b\le0 \iff a+b \le 0
$$ since for example
$$
-11+1=-10\le0 \quad\text{but}\quad 1>0.
$$